# How to better use Opera dragonfly's console methods?

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

I'm trying to use opera dragonfly for debugging, it seems quite nice, but I'm probably doing things wrong here. First problem comes with the console.log() method:

1. In my JavaScript code I just put something like `console.log(someVariable)`
2. When I look at the error tab I can only see reports like `[object MouseEvent]` `[object]` etc.

Most of the time it's completely useless information since I usually already know my variable types. Am I using it wrong? How can I see detailed information about complex variables?

I use console.trace() in my JavaScript code expecting a useful hay stack but nothing happens. When I open up dragonfly console and use the command `console.trace(something)` it always returns undefined. Quite frustrating since I have dragonfly documentation right in front of me now but most of the console methods seems to do nothing useful for me. I really hope I'm using it wrong.

Does anyone knows how to extract really useful information from Dragonfly?

Comment: which version of Opera and Dragonfly are you using?

Comment: Version/11.11, running on Linux x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Dragonfly's console.*() methods are not yet as powerful as Firebug's. They will become more capable over time. As of now, you can not expand the object to discover properties and methods inside the console itself, but you can click an object to have its detail for inspection in the pane for inspecting objects and properties.

Comment: My resignations about it. It's much more practical to set logs inside my scripts, but Dragonfly is still a nice tool and I'll certainly keep using it.